# How to Backup & Restore Dockerize postgres database from Dockerize .NET 6 application programmatically

Tags: postgresql, docker, .net-6.0

I have a postgres database in docker container and .NET 6 Web API in docker container. Both are deployed in linux system. I am able to take backup and restore of postgres database by executing `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` command in host machine.

**Backup:**
`docker exec -u username container-name pg_dump -Ft db-name > db.tar`

**Restore:** `docker exec -i -u username container-name pg_restore -C -d db-name < db.tar`

I want to take a backup of postgres database which is running in docker container from .NET Web API application which is also running in docker container. I am not able to execute `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` command from .NET 6 Web Api container.

Let me know is there any way to take Backup & Restore Dockerize postgres database from Dockerize .NET 6 application programmatically.